Use only 1 formula to populate the information in various columns which are not adjacent
I want to bring the information in table 1 from table 2, from all the column which are common.
ID# is my unique identifier. Also, I cannot delete any columns from any table or re-arrange the columns.
Columns which are in red font indicate that information in these columns are not be changed as they are manually entered.
If I use Vlookup function, then I have to type the formula in the 1st cell of each column to obtain the information, which is time consuming.
With Xlookup the issue that I am having is that the information gets populated in multiple col. only if they are next to each other but if a col. with red font comes in between then xlookup does not populate the correct information in table 1.
So what formula should I use (in cell E6, which I can drag to E12) so that information in all the columns is populated, respectively?


So you dont want to enter any formulas for Columns Named Fruits, Sports, Country and Weather--> just want to enter in Name col and rest will automatically, is that what you are trying to say?

Yes, that is what i am requesting. Put formula in all the cells of the "Name" column only and rest of the information populates, respectively.

So basically you are saying the rest of the columns will be no formulated then it should need VBA otherwise. how could you do that?

That's what i am struggling with. I am not sure how i need to populate the information. Don't know much about VBA. Just need a solution.

Can I convince you to try power query? It's built into Excel. The drawback is that, like pivot tables, changes to source data aren't reflected in the result instantly. You have to refresh the data (e.g. right-clicking on the result and clicking "refresh", clicking "Data - Refresh All" from the ribbon, etc.)
Put your cursor into the first table and then, on the data tab, you can create a query from the first table. The power query editor will pop up and show you what the query result is.
By default, if you close the power query editor and save, any new queries created will be loaded into new sheets and the workbook. For this first query, it's just a duplicate of what you already have. Just delete the new tab if it's created. Don't worry.
Click anywhere in the second table and again, on the data ribbon, load the table as another query.
Now, assuming the queries are named Table1 and Table2, create another query, edit it, click the advanced editor button, and replace its code with
let
  Cols1 = Table.ColumnNames(Table1),
  ColsCommon = List.Intersect(
    Cols1,
    List.RemoveItems(
      Table.ColumnNames(Table2),
      {"ID #"}
    )
  ),
  #"Removed ColsCommon" = Table.RemoveColumns(
    Table1,
    ColsCommon
  ),
  Merged = Table.NestedJoin(
    #"Removed ColsCommon",
    "ID #",
    Table2,
    "ID #",
    "Table2"
  ),
  Expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
    Merged,
    "Table2",
    ColsCommon
  ),
  Reordered = Table.ReorderColumns(
    Expanded,
    Cols1
  )
in
  Reordered

Note: #"Variable Name" is just a way to denote a variable name that contains a space character.
The hard part is that you will then have to debug it; I do not guarantee this works perfectly as is.
The great part is learning a new tool and, if your Table1 or Table2 is actually a separate workbook or CSV file, or a SQL query, then as long as you can make a query for it, this third query can use it!

i tried doing it but unfortunately it does not work.

@Nomi - Where does it fail? Were you able to make the first two queries and see them in the power query editor window that pops up? Is the third query invalid or does it just throw an error in a specific step?
